# Datepart function in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having an issue with datepart month function.
The docnum clearly has a date for this month which 5/23/14 and when I put in the  `datepart(MM,t0.DocDate)=DATEPart(MM,GETDATE())`, the result is empty.
I wonder what could be wrong. strangely it would work for any docnum prior to 23rd of this month, but not after that.

```
select 
   t0.itemcode,
   t1.docnum,
   t0.treetype,
   t1.docdate,
   docstatus,DATEPART(MM,Getdate()),DATEPART(MM,t1.docdate)

from 
   RDR1 t0
inner join ORDR t1 on t1.DocEntry=t0.docentry
inner join dbo.OITM t2 on t2.ItemCode=t0.ItemCode
where 
  t1.DocNum=74464 and datepart(MM,t0.DocDate)=DATEPart(MM,GETDATE()) and
  datepart(YY,t0.DocDate)=DATEPART(YY,Getdate())
  and t1.canceled<>'Y' and
  numatcard not like '%Demo%' and t0.TreeType in ('S','N')
  and t1.U_BP2 is null
```

Comment: What type is `DocDate`?  Can we see some sample data?

Comment: docdate is datetime. This has always worked, just now it didn't.

Comment: SBA-L 74434 N 2014-05-22 00:00:00.000 O 5 5

Comment: Could you post the results with the Month DATEPART criteria removed, and both expressions added to the selection list

Comment: Is there anything else in the where clause there that might be excluding this particular set of documents since 5/23? t1.cancelled = 'Y', t1.DocNum != 74464, t1.cancelled = 'Y' AND t1.DocNum = 74464..?

If you could post some sample data with your before and after WHERE clauses, it would be helpful.

Comment: I have done what you have suggested already, only thing which was causing trouble was the  datepart(MM,t0.DocDate)=DATEPart(MM,GETDATE()) clause and strangely not the  datepart(YY,t0.DocDate)=DATEPART(YY,Getdate())

Comment: select both dateparts and compare the results.

Comment: this looks like a SAP database query, have you removed your where clause and does the query bring back any data? i.e. 
    select 
   t0.itemcode,
   t1.docnum,
   t0.treetype,
   t1.docdate,
   docstatus,DATEPART(MM,Getdate()),DATEPART(MM,t1.docdate)

from 
   RDR1 t0
inner join ORDR t1 on t1.DocEntry=t0.docentry
inner join dbo.OITM t2 on t2.ItemCode=t0.ItemCode

Comment: it seems that I have to use cast with getdate().